# How to programmatically limit buffer size for Eclipse (Message)Console?

Tags: java, logging, eclipse-plugin, console

I develop an Eclipse Plugin that provides a monitoring view containing several instances of `org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsole`, also see

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F

In order to avoid memory issues, I would like to set a maximum size for the buffer of the console, similar to the Eclipse setting for the "normal console view":

> Limit console output, Console buffer size (characters)

If the limit is exceeded I expect the content of my consoles to be rolled, so that the oldest lines are cleared and the newest lines are shown in the console.

=>How can I set a limit for the buffer size? `MessageConsole` does not seem to provide a method `setBufferSize(80000)` or so. It only provides a method `clearConsole()` and no method to determine the current size of the written text.

Is there another implementation of IOConsole that provides the wanted functionality? I could not find something like a `RollingMessageConsole` in the package `org.eclipse.ui.console`:
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fconsole%2Fpackage-summary.html

Where can I find the code that is used in Eclipse to limit the console output?

Below is the current state of my custom Log4J appender that writes messages to my `MessageConsoles`.

```
package org.treez.core.console;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.Layout;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsolePlugin;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsole;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleManager;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsole;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsoleStream;
import org.treez.core.atom.uisynchronizing.AbstractUiSynchronizingAtom;
import org.treez.core.monitor.TreezMonitor;

/**
 * For writing to the eclipse console
 */
public class TreezConsoleAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {


    private static final String CONSOLE_NAME = "TreezConsole";

    private static MessageConsole treezConsole = null;


    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {

        //get formatted message
        Layout layout = this.getLayout();
        String message = layout.format(event);

        String treezMonitorId = event.getNDC();
        MessageConsole console = getConsole(treezMonitorId);

        if (console != null) {

            AbstractUiSynchronizingAtom.runUiTaskNonBlocking(() -> {

                Level level = event.getLevel();

                try (
                        MessageConsoleStream stream = console.newMessageStream();) {

                    if (level.equals(Level.WARN)) {
                        stream.setColor(TreezMonitor.ORANGE);
                    } else if (level.equals(Level.ERROR)) {
                        stream.setColor(TreezMonitor.RED);
                    }

                    stream.println(message);
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

                ThrowableInformation throwableInformation = event.getThrowableInformation();

                if (throwableInformation != null) {

                    Throwable throwable = throwableInformation.getThrowable();

                    try (
                            MessageConsoleStream stream = console.newMessageStream();) {
                        if (level.equals(Level.WARN)) {
                            stream.setColor(TreezMonitor.ORANGE);
                        } else if (level.equals(Level.ERROR)) {
                            stream.setColor(TreezMonitor.RED);
                        }

                        throwable.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(stream));

                    } catch (IOException exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        //not used here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * If a non-null jobId is specified: returns the console for the given jobId or null if no corresponding console has
     * been registered for the TreezMonitors. If the given jobId is null, the (single) TreezConsole is returned.
     */
    private static MessageConsole getConsole(String treezMonitorId) {
        if (treezMonitorId == null) {
            if (treezConsole == null) {
                createTreezConsole();
            }
            return treezConsole;
        } else {
            return TreezMonitor.getConsole(treezMonitorId);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates the console
     */
    private static void createTreezConsole() {
        IConsoleManager consoleManager = getConsoleManager();
        if (consoleManager != null) {
            IConsole[] existingConsoles = consoleManager.getConsoles();
            //check if console already exists and save it if so
            for (IConsole currentConsole : existingConsoles) {
                String currentConsoleName = currentConsole.getName();
                boolean isWantedConsole = CONSOLE_NAME.equals(currentConsoleName);
                if (isWantedConsole) {
                    treezConsole = (MessageConsole) currentConsole;
                    return;
                }
            }

            //console does not already exist: create new one
            treezConsole = new MessageConsole(CONSOLE_NAME, null);          
            consoleManager.addConsoles(new IConsole[] { treezConsole });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the eclipse console manager
     */
    private static IConsoleManager getConsoleManager() {
        ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
        if (plugin != null) {
            IConsoleManager consoleManager = plugin.getConsoleManager();
            return consoleManager;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: The buffer size settings hide in `IOConsole::setWaterMarks()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is set using the

```
public void setWaterMarks(int low, int high)
```

method of `IOConsole` (which `MessageConsole` extends).

The JavaDoc says

> Sets the text buffer size for this console. The high water mark
>   indicates the maximum number of characters stored in the buffer. The
>   low water mark indicates the number of characters remaining in the
>   buffer when the high water mark is exceeded.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I thought watermark would mean some sort of background image. Therefore I did not consider that method to be relevant.